# Orthogonal and Diagonal Matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonality

[image]

I was wondering how to find the P and D matrices. I have tried using algebra for each element and knowing that the orthogonal means that $P^{-1} =P^T$ and that a diagonal matrix means that there are only non-zero elements along the diagonal. But I do not know the correct approach to take. If anyone could step me in the correct direction it would be very appreactiated!

Comment: No solution because if $P$ is orthogonal, i.e., $P^{-1}=P^T$, the decomposition would imply that $A$ is real-symmetric.

Comment: Please take the time to enter core parts of your question as text instead of simply pasting a picture. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.